# Как в jquery установить maxlength для другого поля text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно в первом input type="text" считать длину и устанавливать ее во втором input type="text" как maxlength.

Пока смог добиться что в первом можно посчитать и вывести длину и по клику вывести значение длины. Но, не получается задавать maxlength без клика, а по факту заполнения (или по таймеру) первого input type="text" и установить это значение как значение длины maxlength для второго. И чтобы делалось не по событию, а по таймеру например, чтобы пользователь не кликал и не нажимал ничего.

Вот тут, то что удалось пока добиться своими корявыми руками

```js
function f1() {
  $('#cartag').on('click', function() {
    var input = $(this);
    var input_lenght = input.val().length;
    input.next("span").text(input_lenght + " chars");
    //console.log(input_lenght);
    return input_lenght;
  });
}

//f1();


$('#cartag222').on('click', function() {
  var limitvalue = f1();
  console.log(limitvalue);
  limitText(this, limitvalue);
});

function limitText(field, maxChar) {
  var ref = $(field),
    val = ref.val();
  if (val.length >= maxChar) {
    ref.val(function() {
      //console.log(val.substr(0, maxChar))
      return val.substr(0, maxChar);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cartag" type="text" name="car"><span></span>

<input id="cartag222" type="text" name="car222">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если я вас правильно понял, то можно так. при изменении значения первого инпута, устанавливается значение `maxlength` второго.

**С jquery**

```js
$('#cartag').on("change", function(){
  
  $('#cartag222').attr('maxlength', $(this).val().length);
  console.log('maxlength for $("#cartag222"): ' + $(this).val().length)
  $("span").text($(this).val().length)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cartag" type="text" name="car"><span></span>

<input id="cartag222" type="text" name="car222">
```

---

**Без использования jquery**

```js
let cartag = document.getElementById("cartag");
let cartag222 = document.getElementById("cartag222");
let out = document.getElementById("out");


cartag.addEventListener("change", () => {
  cartag222.setAttribute("maxlength", cartag.value.length)
  out.innerText = cartag.value.length
  console.log(`maxlength is: ${cartag.value.length}`)
})
```

```html
<input id="cartag" type="text" name="car"><span id="out"></span>

<input id="cartag222" type="text" name="car222">
```

Comment: Наверно все такие я не понятно объяснил. В вашем примере вводим в первое поле например текст длиной 5 - ABSD4 , при этом максимальная длина для второго поля должна стать 5 . У вас в примере оно не ограничивется, можно вводить сколько угодно по длине.

Comment: @DimaKuzmin смените `$('#cartag222').attr('maxlength', $(this).val());` на `$('#cartag222').attr('maxlength', $(this).val().length);`

Comment: @DimaKuzmin Добавил вычисление длины

Comment: @DimaKuzmin добавил вариант без использования jquery

Comment: Если выводите length то лучше это на keyup делать

Comment: @InDevX один из вариантов реализации)))